# Notation: When to imply and when to express equivalence?

Tags: notation, propositional-calculus

I have recently been trying to improve the readability of my work as I solve equations, so that I and others can easily navigate how exactly I solved them. I want to make sure I using proper notation. In my search I come across [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1748289/notation-for-equivalent-equations), but was left pondering the accepted answer.

In the question, it is asked whether using the logical implication symbol is valid for showing that an equation has been rearranged. *For example:*$$\alpha\beta=\gamma\Rightarrow\alpha=\frac{\gamma}{\beta}$$

The accepted answer asserts that this is correct, but that one can also use the logical biconditional symbol. *For example:*$$\alpha\beta=\gamma\Leftrightarrow \alpha=\frac{\gamma}{\beta}$$

In the answer (and comments) it is implied that the context of the equation will determine which to use. I have taken a course in propositional logic and understand what these operators mean from a truth table perspective, but am unclear on when to use what?

***My question:***
In what situations should I use an implication to demonstrate the equation has been rearranged and in what situations should I use biconditional/equivalence to show this?

Answer (score 2):

When the biconditional is legitimate (i.e., when there really is equivalence between the statements), it never hurts to indicate so, and IMO it's *always* a good idea to use it. This way you can tell if your chain of reasoning is totally reversible, and if it's not reversible, you know which step is the culprit.

Even if the result you're trying to establish is one-way (meaning you're not required to prove the converse), a step that lacks the biconditional is a signal to you and other observers that there may be 'loss of equivalence' at that point.